# Find list of directories one level deep from matching directory

Tags: bash, find, directory, ls

I'm trying to get a list of directories that are contained within a specific folder.

Given these example folders:

```
foo/bar/test
foo/bar/test/css
foo/bar/wp-content/plugins/XYZ
foo/bar/wp-content/plugins/XYZ/js
foo/bar/wp-content/plugins/XYZ/css
baz/wp-content/plugins/ABC
baz/wp-content/plugins/ABC/inc
baz/wp-content/plugins/ABC/inc/lib
baz/wp-content/plugins/DEF
bat/bar/foo/blog/wp-content/plugins/GHI
```

I'd like a command that will return:

```
XYZ
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Essentially, I'm looking for the folders that are inside of wp-content/plugins/

Using `find` has gotten me the closest, but I can't use `-maxdepth`, because the folder is variably away from where I'm searching.

Running the following returns all of the child directories, recursively.

`find -type d -path *wp-content/plugins/*`

```
foo/bar/wp-content/plugins/XYZ
foo/bar/wp-content/plugins/XYZ/js
foo/bar/wp-content/plugins/XYZ/css
baz/wp-content/plugins/ABC
baz/wp-content/plugins/ABC/inc
baz/wp-content/plugins/ABC/inc/lib
baz/wp-content/plugins/DEF
bat/bar/foo/blog/wp-content/plugins/GHI
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just add a `-prune` so that the found directories are not descended into:

```
find . -type d -path '*/wp-content/plugins/*' -prune -print
```

You need to quote that `*wp-content/plugins/*` as it's also a shell glob.

If you want only the directory names as opposed to their full path, with GNU `find`, you can replace the `-print` with `-printf '%f\n'` or assuming the file paths don't contain newline characters, pipe the output of the above command to `awk -F / '{print $NF}'` or `sed 's|.*/||'` (also assuming the file paths contain only valid characters).

With `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' **/wp-content/plugins/*(D/:t)
```

`**/` is any level of subdirectories (feature originating in `zsh` in the early nighties, and now found in most other shells like `ksh93`, `tcsh`, `fish`, `bash`, `yash` though generally under some option), `(/)` to select only files of type *directory*, `D` to include hidden (dot) ones, `:t` to get the *tail* (file name).

Comment: This find will convert newlines in dirs to a `?`. For bash, (as tagged in the question) [this works](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/348120/190466).

Comment: @sorontar, `find` implementations that output a `?` or any replacement character or any form of escaping for non-printable characters only do that when the output goes to a terminal, not when it goes to a pipe like here.

Comment: The first (and only non zsh) command that is in your answer has no pipes, it is the one I tested, and is the one that change newlines. When piped, as your said: "assuming the file paths don't contain newline characters", so, you already admitted that it also fails with newlines.

Comment: @sorontar, sorry I thought you were commenting on the second part to say that it would work OK as the newlines would be escaped so would not break the assumption we're making for `sed`/`awk` that all files are on a line. Now, One may argue that getting a `ABC?BCD` or `ABC\nBCD` for interactive/terminal output would be more useful than getting two `ABC` and `BCD` lines for a dir called `$'ABC\nBCD`. That's at the level of user presentation, we could also point out that for a file called `$'AB\bC'`, when the output goes to a terminal, you'd see `AC` without such a `?` replacement...

Comment: Find with -prune and using printf to modify the output format gave me exactly what I was asking for. Perfect--thanks!

Comment: `-prune` seems most appropriate when working with trees ;-)

Comment: @MikedD, that's exactly what it stands for. It does prune that branch of the directory tree.

Answer (score 7):

You could have `find` recurse, sort of:

```
find / -type d -path *wp-content/plugins -exec find {} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Bash-ically:

```
shopt -s globstar
printf "%s\n" **/wp-content/plugins/*
```

prints:

```
bat/bar/foo/blog/wp-content/plugins/GHI
baz/wp-content/plugins/ABC
baz/wp-content/plugins/DEF
foo/bar/wp-content/plugins/XYZ
```

or

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/wp-content/plugins/*; do printf "%s\n" ${d##*/}; done
```

prints:

```
GHI
ABC
DEF
XYZ
```

Comment: Nope, that will print files inside the dirs as well. Please read my answer.

Comment: Good point; thank you! I had recreated their directory structure, but not placed test files in them.

Answer (score 3):

The `tree` command is designed exactly for this purpose. The depth can be controlled with the `-L` flag. Here is an example on a local Wordpress site that I maintain:

```
$ tree -L 1 wp-content/
wp-content/
├── index.php
├── plugins
└── themes

2 directories, 1 file

$ tree -L 2 wp-content/
wp-content/
├── index.php
├── plugins
│   ├── akismet
│   ├── contact-form-7
│   ├── index.php
│   └── wordpress-seo
└── themes
    ├── index.php
    ├── twentyfifteen
    └── twentysixteen

11 directories, 3 files

$ tree -L 1 wp-content/plugins/
wp-content/plugins/
├── akismet
├── contact-form-7
├── index.php
└── wordpress-seo

5 directories, 1 file
```

Answer (score 3):

For Bash: Simple (works for files/dirs with **spaces** and **newlines**):

```
shopt -s globstar                    # allow ** for several dirs.
a=(**/wp-content/plugins/*/)         # capture only wanted dirs.
a=("${a[@]%/}")                      # remove trailing slash (dirs) `/`.
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]##*/}"          # print only the last dir name.
```

Wll print:

```
GHI
ABC
DEF
XYZ
```

Even if there are files created.

Comment: Note that it doesn't look inside hidden dirs, skips hidden files (see the `dotglob` option if that's unwanted) and includes symlinks to directories in addition to directories (`**` would also traverse symlinks in bash 4.2 and earlier).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas hidden files? The question asks for none, only dirs. Yes, hidden dirs could be independently selected (as a feature, if desired). And yes, symlinks are not transverse in the current version of bash.

Comment: please don't regard my comments as aggressions. I upvoted your answer and added a note underneath to point out some facts about it that are not necessarily obvious. `find` doesn't exclude any file. globs excludes dot files, it's worth pointing out as a difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Building on DopeGhoti's answer, how about loop of matching:

```
find / -type d -iregex '.*/wp-content/plugins' -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' D; do
    find "$D" -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 1
done
```

Reason for doing it this way is that you may find it confusing/cumbersome with multiple `-exec`'s, whilst still avoiding issues with peculiar file names containing \n ' ', etc. -print0 will use null separators between results.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what you started:

```
find -type d -path *wp-content/plugins/* | egrep -o "wp-content/plugins/[^/]+($|/)" | sed -r "s~wp-content/plugins/([^/]+)($|/)~\1~" | uniq
```

**egrep** grabs *wp-content/plugins/* and any characters up to the next slash / or end of line $ - which includes the portion you want.

**sed**, with a ~ delimiter, selects the portion you want using the first set of parenthesis () and uses \1 (what you want) as the replacement of everything

**uniq** filters out duplicate results